# How to show a server side error message in a popup using php

Tags: php, javascript, thickbox

I found some of the similar questions here but they are all in C#.

So kindly tell me the easiest way to show the server side error message using popup.

The popup may be anything like thickbox, modalpopup etc...

Here is the sample code. I didn't get the error message in the popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox/thickbox.js"></script>
<link href="thickbox/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<span class="prtexterror" style="color:#FF0000;display:none;" id="hiddenModalContent" >{$error_login}</span>


{literal}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



  $(document).ready(function() {
    tb_show("Please, login", "?tb_inline=true&inlineId=hiddenModalContent&height=180&width=300&modal=true", null);
});



</script>
{/literal}
```

Any other ways are always welcome. 
thanks in advance

Comment: It is not PHP. it is some unidentified template with some javascript. What is the question anyway? It looks like your question javascript-related, not PHP. What exactly do you call with "server side error message"? what is the scenario? In general, any server side message is like any other server-generated content. Just print out anything you want, including any javascript code

Comment: my problem is i validate a login form using php and it's throwing a error message in the same page. But i need to throw the error message in a popup.

Comment: hereby, i mentioned only the error message and java script part.

Comment: ahh I see now, your question is thickbox related. you just don't know how to throw a popup using thickbox - right?

Comment: Yes, i don't know how to throw a popup after the completion of server side validation

Comment: Sorry mate I have no idea what this thickbox is.

Comment: then the title should be renamed *"How to show a server side error message in a popup using **thickbox** "* or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Generally, PHP's going to spew its errors into the output HTML stream when they occur, unless you've got the .ini setting "display_errors" set to off. If you want to display them in a modal popup (alert box, floating div, etc..), you'll have to add the appropriate logic into the script to capture them:

```
<?php

$val = some_function_that_causes_an_error();
if (error_get_last()) {
    $lasterror = error_get_last();
}
```

[error_get_last()](http://php.net/error_get_last) returns an array, follow the link to the PHP docs to see what the format is.

Later on in your page you'd have to convert the error into whatever format you want it displayed. A basic setup would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var errmsg = <?php echo json_encode($lasterror) ?>;

alert('Server error of type ' + errmsg.type + ' at line ' + errmsg.line + ' in script ' + errmsg.file + ': ' + errmsg.message);

</script>
```

Also, remember that fatal errors (syntax errors, out of memory, etc...) cannot be trapped and will abort the script, so unless you're accessing the script via AJAX, you're going to get a blank page or a partial page that ends with the PHP error message.